# implement wechat authentication in cordova hybrid app ios

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap, wechat

I am developing a cordova hybrid app targeting ios & need to add authentication via wechat in login page.

```
$scope.wechatLogin=function(){
 scope = "snsapi_userinfo",state = "_" + (+new Date());
 Wechat.auth(scope, state, function (response) {
 alert(JSON.stringify(response));           

 $.get('https://api.weixin.qq.com/sns/oauth2/access_token?myappid=' + appId + '&secret=' + myappSecret + '&code=' + response.code + '&grant_type=authorization_code', function (accessTokenResponse) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(accessTokenResponse));
            // you should save access token response somewhere, e.g. cookies, local storage, etc.
            var accessToken = accessTokenResponse.access_token;
            var openId = accessTokenResponse.openid;
            // get user information
            $.get('https://api.weixin.qq.com/sns/userinfo?access_token=' + accessToken + '&openid=' + openId + '&lang=zh_CN', function (userInfoResponse) {
                console.log(userInfoResponse);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

when testing this in device, it opens wechat & gives a message as "oops! Something went wrong". Can You help me to resolve this.

Thank you very much!